# How do I interpret this Wireshark log file?

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis

I'm new to using Wireshark and I'd like some help with analyzing the log shown in the image. 

I also ran a nmap scan of the ports on my computer, but I'm not able to identify which of these lines are related to the port scan.[image: Wireshark log]

Comment: It doesn't appear that you captured a port scan.  What is the source IP of your scanner?

Comment: @RonTrunk I used the command `nmap -sT localhost` to run the scan, so I'm assuming that the source IP is that of my machine

Comment: Have you configured it to capture on the localchost (`127.0.0.1`) virtual interface?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot doesn't show a port scan.

With a TCP port scan you'd see a number of (unACKed) SYN packets for incrementing TCP port numbers. For UDP, you'd see incrementing port numbers as well.

You might have scanned and captured different interfaces.